# What are the actual on/off/sleep states for and how do you hard reset a Kindle WiFi?

Tags: kindle, hardware, power-management

I recently purchased a Kindle device (the current non Touch WiFi model) for an [AP](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q%22aged%20parent%22%20literature). I don't live locally but that doesn't get me off the hook for supporting it. Unfortunately, as my device is the Paperwhite, I am unable to compare with how my device behaves. I recently received this communique:

> The Kindle will no longer  boot up - if that is the correct term. All I get is a gray screen. If one holds the on button for a few sec it will momentarily go dark but nothing else happens

I suspect that the device has never really been turned off and on and is at this juncture just locked up. On my device there is a sleep mode that is the normal way to turn it on or off and when it does lock up it can be very difficult to get it unstuck. However I have never seen a mode that responds with a screen clear (I assume that in the "momentary go dark") but then does nothing.

**What mode could this device be stuck in and how do you give in a hard-reset so that the firmware actually does a "cold boot"?**

Comment: The manual suggests you should plug it in for some time (to make sure it has enough power) and then hold the power button for at least 15 seconds (make it more) .On the Kindle 3, the power led should blink if you held it long enough, I am not sure about the Kindle 4 however.

Comment: It may need to be charged.  My Nook color will do this when it does not have enough power to turn on long enough to tell me that it does not have enough power to turn on...

Answer (score 1):

As already commented,  plug in the Kindle 4 to the wall or your Mac/PC.  Let it charge for a bit -- even 15 minutes will help.  Leave it plugged in,  and press and hold the power button till the screen flashes. Wait a minute to see if it is doing a reboot. When that probably isn't enough,  do it again.  I've heard the number "5 times"  and I've experienced needing at least 4 times (actually, I wasn't counting).  The screen will flash, and after a few times of this,  it will finally continue past the flash and will begin a full reboot.

After 4 or 5 of these freeze ups, I decided my battery might be aging, and started recharging it every night.  It can't hurt.  I also kept my eye open for a cheap spare K4, just in case.